# GAE Dashboard - Why in tasks logs the cost is not shown?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, task, dashboard

In every log of each request in GAE, there is the approximate cost of each one, like this:
[image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMK4i.png) for higher resolution image

As shown in [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?hl=it&csw=1#Responses), that is the cost for 1000 requests

```
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars
An estimate of what 1,000 requests similar to this request would cost in US dollars.
```

Why this information does not appears in task queue logs?

Answer (score 0):

There are in Logs page on Dashboard (https://appengine.google.com).

Comment: Sorry but in the logs page (where i got the above screenshot) there is no "cpm_usd" label for logs related to task queues

Answer (score 0):

It may have been simply overlooked in the implementation.  There may be no exact specification for the task queue log format.  Consider filing a feature request.